# Test en laravel, como comprobar si el menu admin se esta cargando en usuarios normales

Tags: php, laravel, test

tengo una app con dos roles: **admin** y **staff**.
Si es admin cargara, a parte de staff, unos menus extras. Lo tengo dividido por partials.

Tengo el partial de menu. Este se compone por **menu.admin** y **menu.staff**. Ambos estan en includes diferentes quedando algo asi

### Menu.blade

```
{{-- ADMIN MENU --}}
@role('admin')
    @include('modules.menu-bar-left-admin')
@endrole

{{-- STAFF MENU --}}
@hasanyrole('admin|staff')
    @include('modules.menu-bar-left-staff')
@endrole
```

Entonces quiero hacer unos test para comprobar que en caso de que el usuario logeado sea user de tipo admin cargue ambos includes, y en caso de que sea un staff solo cargue la que pone staff menu.

En los tests tengo esto:

```
public function testStaffMustNotSeeAdminMenus()
    {
        $user = User::factory()->create();
        $user->assignRole('staff');

        Auth::login($user);

        $this->get('/home');
        
        //aqui deberia comprobar si se estan cargando el menu de los admin

    }
```

Pero no consigo encontrar algo como `assertIncludes` o algo que me sea de utilidad para este caso.

Comment: Prueba con alguno de los asserts de testing views https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-tests#testing-views

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ estoy mirando y probando, pero no doy con nada que me sirva. De todas formas muchas gracias, voy a estar mirando por el link que me mendastes algo que pueda usar